# C, C++ extract struct member from binary file

Tags: c++, c, struct, binary, fopen

I'm using the following code to extract a struct member from a binary file.

I'm wondering why this prints out multiple times? when there is only one ID record, and only one struct in the file. I need to access just this member, what is the best way to do it?

I don't really understand what the while loop is doing? Is it testing for whether the file is open and returning 1 until that point?

Why use fread inside the while loop?

Does the fread need to be set to the specific size of the struct member?

Is the printf statement reading the binary and outputting an int?

```
FILE *p;
struct myStruct x;
p=fopen("myfile","rb");

while(1) {
    size_t n = fread(&x, sizeof(x), 1, p);
    if (n == 0) {
        break;
    }
    printf("\n\nID:%d", x.ID);  // Use matching specifier
    fflush(stdout); // Insure output occurs promptly
}
fclose(p);
return 0;
```

The struct looks like this:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int cm;    
    int bytes;          
    int ID; 
    int version; 
    char chunk[1];     
}
```

Comment: Why are you unsure whether this is C or C++? You know how you are compiling it ... right?

Comment: I can use both at the same time...

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one struct in the file?

Comment: Yes I am sure there is only one struct

Comment: In a single source code? No you can't.

Comment: Its compiled as c++, but thats irrelevant to the question...

Comment: What is the size of the file? What is the value of `n` after `fread`

Comment: The total file size is 2906 bytes

Comment: it is not irrelevant to the question, because in C++ you would usually not use C i/o unless you have some good reasons to do so

Comment: 2906 is a lot more than the size of 4 integers - typically 16 bytes - hence more than one struct

Comment: Sorry there is one large chunk at the end I forgot to include in the struct.

Comment: I think you have answered this question

Comment: Hi Ed I definitely havent, still cant access the data in x.ID

Comment: You keep reading the same structure time and time again until the file is exhausted.

Comment: Is there any chance you can post an example as to how you would capture x.ID member?

Comment: @Ke. `Sorry there is one large chunk at the end I forgot to include in the struct` Then you should update your Q so that readers won't be confused about the size mismatch.

Comment: @Ke. - Can you show the code used for creating the file?

Comment: @EdHeal has it right.  Variable length structure....

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer but to answer a comment.

Just do

```
FILE *p = fopen("myfile","rb");
struct myStruct x;

size_t n = fread(&x, sizeof(x), 1, p);
if (n != 1) {
    // Some error message
} else {
    printf("\n\nID:%d\n", x.ID);
}

...Do as you wish with the rest of the file
```

Comment: this is to make sure that there is only a single struct in the file, right?

Comment: @4386427 - You are correct - in my haste I made a mistake

Comment: @tobi303 - No - But my comment _Do as you ..._ implies this

Comment: I dont really understand what this answers, however I also dont really understand what is the question, there are just to many `?` in there

Comment: Hi, this just prints ID: 0 and I'm sure there is an ID 6 or so digits long in x.ID , am I possibly using the wrong type or something? Is there any way to test that data exists inside the ID member?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering why this prints out multiple times? when there is only one ID record, and only one struct in the file.

It won't! So if you have multiple prints the likely explanation is that the file contains more than just **one** struct. Another explanation could be that the file (aka the struct) was not saved in the same way as you use for reading.

> I need to access just this member, what is the best way to do it?

Your approach looks fine to me.

> I don't really understand what the while loop is doing?

The `while` is there because the code should be able to read multiple structs from the file. Using `while(1)` means something like "loop forever". To get out of such a loop, you use `break`. In your code the `break` happens when it can't read more structs from the file, i.e. `if (n == 0) { break; }`

> Is it testing for whether the file is open and returning 1 until that point?

No - see answer above.

> Why use fread inside the while loop?

As above: To able to read multiple structs from the file

> Does the fread need to be set to the specific size of the struct member?

Well, `fread` is not "set" to anything. It is told how many elements to read and the **size** of each element. Therefore you call it with `sizeof(x)`.

> Is the printf statement reading the binary and outputting an int?

No, the reading is done by `fread`. Yes, `printf` outputs the decimal value.

You can try out this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct myStruct
{
    int cm;    
    int bytes;          
    int ID; 
    int version; 
    char chunk[1];     
};

void rr()
{
  printf("Reading file\n");

  FILE *p;
  struct myStruct x;
  p=fopen("somefile","rb");

  while(1) {
    size_t n = fread(&x, sizeof(x), 1, p);
    if (n == 0) {
      break;
    }
    printf("\n\nID:%d", x.ID);  // Use matching specifier
    fflush(stdout); // Insure output occurs promptly
  }
  fclose(p);
}

void ww()
{
  printf("Creating file containing a single struct\n");

  FILE *p;
  struct myStruct x;
  x.cm = 1;    
  x.bytes = 2;          
  x.ID = 3; 
  x.version = 4; 
  x.chunk[0] = 'a';     

  p=fopen("somefile","wb");

  fwrite(&x, sizeof(x), 1, p);
  fclose(p);
}



int main(void) {
  if( access( "somefile", F_OK ) == -1 ) 
  {
    // If "somefile" isn't there already, call ww to create it
    ww();
  }

  rr();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers in-line

I'm wondering why this prints out multiple times? when there is only one ID record, and only one struct in the file. I need to access just this member, what is the best way to do it?

> > The file size is 2906 bytes and fread is only reading sone 17 bytes at a time, and this goes on in a loop

I don't really understand what the while loop is doing? Is it testing for whether the file is open and returning 1 until that point?

> > The total number of elements successfully read is returned by fread

Why use fread inside the while loop?

> > In this case while is not necessary. just one fread is enough. Fread is sometimes used in a while loop when input from some other source like UART is being processed and the program has to wait for the said number of bytes t be read

Does the fread need to be set to the specific size of the struct member?

> > No. Reading the entire struct is better

Is the printf statement reading the binary and outputting an int?

> > No