# Accessing member of struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, binary, fopen

I'm trying to access some data member inside a binary file, using a struct definition.

Inside thi file, it should contain a struct member called fxID. In the following code, I'm trying to access fxID, but it's not working, it's returning an incorrect number. Even more strangely, if I change fxID to fxVersion, I get the same number, so it does appear that the printf is not picking up the correct data at all.

```
FILE *p;
struct myStruct x;
p=fopen("myfile.fxb","rb");

size_t n = fread(&x, sizeof(x), 1, p);
if (n != 1) {
    // Some error message
    //printf("%i", sizeof(x));
} else {
    printf("\n\nID:%d\n",  x.fxID);
}
```

Any idea why I can't access the data inside fxID? I'm getting strange results depending on what type I use in the printf statement. For instance, I get the number 1606416148 if I use printf("%d", x.fxID); However, this is wrong, because I believe the fxID is 1447514692. Is this because of the endianness? I know the file is big endian and it mentions something about needing to convert it in the header file I linked to.

Could it be due to using Int? or the wrong type perhaps?

Comment: I think I have deja-vous - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556266/c-c-extract-struct-member-from-binary-file/39556551#comment66424088_39556551

Comment: Might need a marker at the start of the file as to the version i.e. `VST_2_4_EXTENSIONS`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add that in my own struct definition, I'm removing the if statement, and I'm still trying to understand why I cannot access data inside structs in a meaningful way. Still haven't found a solution for the problems Im encountering.

Comment: You need to have a version marker then serialize the data when writing (perhaps put stuff in network order) and the deserialise when reading

Comment: Hi Ed, Im not writing this data, only reading at the moment. How to deserialise when reading??

Comment: Hi user3121023, this doesnt work im afraid, it just gives me the data for the first member of the struct (chunkMagic), when it should be giving me the fxID

Comment: This is C++, you don't have to write `struct myStruct x`, just `myStruct x` will do.

Answer (score 1):

Endianess must be corrected for sure if the one used in the file is different from the one used by the platform. If the format is stored using big endian layout then, if you are working on x64, you will have to swap the bytes of each multi-byte field.

But this is not enough to guarantee that the layout of your `struct` is the same of the one used in the file format as it could contain padding and alignment requirements, so in general if you want to deserialize binary data directly inside a `struct` you must take care of multiple things.

In any case if the obtained result is 16064`1`6148 and you were expecting `1447514692` then endianness is not the only problem since both in hex are respectively `0x5FBFF714` and `0x56475244` which are not the same value with different endianness.

**You are using `&x.fxID` which returns the address of the `fxID` field inside the struct, which is not the value, try to use `x.fxID` directy.**

Comment: ok, have changed to x.fxID directly, and now it's returning 0. I'm wondering why that is? It should be 1447514692. I also cannot access the other parts of the struct, such as fxVersion. Any chance you could check with the file I attached to confirm?

Comment: Strangely, when I use x.byteSize it is giving me a hex value of 6b427846 which is kBxF, this backwards (due to big endian) is FxBk. So why is the FxBk message coming out in the variable byteSize, when it should be found in fxMagic?? Clearly the data is misaligned somehow?